# What is the scope of "$this" and what are the drawbacks of using it?

Tags: magento-1.7, template

Having basic knowledge of JAVA, I understand that usually **"this" keyword** is used for **local references** made within a class.

But as far as PHP OOP is concerned, and more specifically **as far as Magento** is concerned, what is the **scope of "$this"** which is used to make references (for example, calling methods, etc.) everywhere within block files, template files.. and so on??

What are the drawbacks if we make this kind of direct references through "$this"??

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$this` still refers to the current object in PHP (and Magento also).
The fact that you see it outside a class is just a side effect of how Magento works.
Technically you are still inside a class when using it in template file.
See how this method looks `Mage_Core_Block_Template::fetchView()`. This is the method responsible for rendering a block via a template.
Notice this code:

```
$includeFilePath = realpath($this->_viewDir . DS . $fileName);
if (strpos($includeFilePath, realpath($this->_viewDir)) === 0 || $this->_getAllowSymlinks()) {
    include $includeFilePath;
} else {
    Mage::log('Not valid template file:'.$fileName, Zend_Log::CRIT, null, null, true);
}
```

The template file is actually included in the method.
The think that must look strange to you if you come from the world of JAVA is how `include` works for PHP.

Comment: Thanks.....Now consider a scenario where, I have two methods. One comes from Block.php, the other from Helper class i.e Data.php. I attempt to use both of these methods in a single file using "$this". Is it first possible and technically correct? If  yes, then how magento differentiates between two "$this" variable??

Comment: You cannot use `$this` to call a method from the helper in a block class. Use `Mage::helper('alias_here')->doSomething()`

Comment: Alright... That was indeed a good explanation. Makes things more clear for me to understand now... Thanks @Marius